# debug published web application asp.net

Tags: asp.net, debugging, build, publish

How can I debug a Published website. I am using VS 2008. And My web Application works fine in my local environment, but when I published the application and moved to Production I am getting some errors. I am trying to do some IO operations, and I set full rights to ASP.Net user to the specified directory, same as my local machine. One major problem I am facing is my production box don't have VS 2008 installed. Only .Net 3.5 and VS 2005 available. How can debug my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform [Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) (you need to run `msvsmon.exe` on the remote machine and then you can attach the Visual Studio Debugger to the process hosting your application - w3wp.exe if running IIS). But before going into that I would probably first check the EventLog for more information about the error.